# Retractions surjectivity doubts

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider $A \subset X$ a retract of the topological space $X$. Are there examples of a retraction $r: X \rightarrow A$ which are not surjective?

Comment: By definition a retract is identity map on A, so it is necessarily a surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much @Yilong Zhang, I needed this confirmation!

Answer (score 3):

For a subspace $A\subset X$ let $i\colon A \to X$ be inclusion of $A$ into $X$. We say $A$ is a retract of $X$ if there exists an $r\colon X \to A$ such that $r\circ i = \operatorname{Id}_A$ and in such a case call $r$ a retraction.

As $\operatorname{Id}_A$ is surjective, $r$ must also be surjective.